# brew install elasticsearch on M1 macbook results in "Bad CPU type in executable" error

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I have a fresh Macbook Air with **M1** processor

Following official guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html I've tried to install elasticsearch 7 with:

```
brew tap elastic/tap
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

once I try to start it with `$ elasticsearch` I get this error:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/elasticsearch-full/7.16.2/libexec/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 83: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/elasticsearch-full/7.16.2/libexec/jdk.app/Contents/Home/bin/java: Bad CPU type in executable
```

If I try to start the service with `brew services start elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full` It will fails and I'll get same error in log file `/opt/homebrew/var/log/elasticsearch.log`

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/elasticsearch-full/7.16.2/libexec/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 83: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/elasticsearch-full/7.16.2/libexec/jdk.app/Contents/Home/bin/java: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Once I open the file (`elasticsearch-env`) that causes the issue line 83 reads:

```
# check the Java version
"$JAVA" "$XSHARE" -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker
```

If I try to execute

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/elasticsearch-full/7.16.2/libexec/jdk.app/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

I get the error

```
 Bad CPU type in executable
```

So it seems a bad Java architecture was installed during the elasticsearch-full brew instalation (maybe instead of M1 it's x84 or something ?). This is fresh new Macbook bought couple of hours ago. Elasticsearch was first thing I've tried to brew install on it (so no prior Java application installed)

Anyone knows how to solve this pretty please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the issue was that I needed to install the Java JDK separately.

I've just installed [Java OSX ARM DMG](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac) and then ES was working

As long as `$ java -version` don't throw you an error this error will not appear

Comment: also in order to change Memory consumption for Elasticsearch I recommend checking https://blog.eq8.eu/til/change-elasticsearch-memory-usage-on-osx-macbook-homebrew.html By defaulth ES consume a lot of memory

Answer (score 10):

You can also fix this by installing Rosetta 2 on your ARM Mac:
`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`.

Apparently brew still installs the 64 bit version of elasticsearch.